# structure implementation for linked list

Tags: data-structures

When I was reading about Linked list, I came to know that the structure for linked list as

```
Struct node{           
   Struct node *next;  
   int value;  
}
```

Why is the Struct node *next? Why cant it just be an integer pointer? Like below

```
Struct node{   
   int *next;  
   int value;  
}
```

why can't this hold the next node's address? Can anyone please give me explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the Struct node *next? Why cant
>   it just be an integer pointer?

Because then [you would be pointing to the address](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) of the next integer. This could be used to retrieve the value of the next int, but nothing more, so from there on onward, you would be stuck.

By linking nodes together, which hold integer values, you can traverse the nodes and retrieve the int values.

Comment: why cant it be some thing like                                            nodeNext=(node *) malloc(sizeof(node *));                                                                            next=&nodeNext;                                                        *next (will give next node's address) and *(next+1) (will give "value")

Comment: @Senthilnathan: do you fully understand the concept of pointers? I presume the programming language you are using is C. If yes, please refer to Chapter 5 (about Pointers and Arrays) of K&R book. And then refer to Chapter 6 (its about structures).

Answer (score 2):

That's actually what a pointer (`*next`) does. It holds the *address* of something else. The type definition describes *what* this something else is (in this case `struct node`). Otherwise the application would not know how many bytes to read and how to interpret the data.

[Read more about pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29).

---

Btw. `int *next` would hold the address of an integer.

Comment: why cant it be like                                            nodeNext=(node *) malloc(sizeof(node *));                                                                            next=&nodeNext;

Comment: @Senthilnathan: Not really sure what you are trying to do, but seems much more complicated. Why do you want to make it more complicated? As I said, `next` already contains the address of the next node.